# Python ImportError: No module named requests when requirements are already satisfied

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests, python-module

I am using Linux server envirnoment and trying to execute simple python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import requests
```

After execution i get this error:

```
File "./tele.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I tried all possible options and also searched earlier threads to resolve the issue but sadly nothing worked so far

Options I tried:

Install virtual environment and tried pip install request.

```
pip install requests
```

Also, tried uninstalling global request library and install only in virtual env.

It is also getting installed and also giving me message as below:

```
  Downloading requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     |################################| 61 kB 31.3 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /home/tguser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /home/tguser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/tguser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /home/tguser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (1.26.2)
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.25.1
```

Also, tried to add python3 forcefully in my script but that is also not working

One more option tried:

```
import urllib3.requests
```

pip list is showing the module request,

```
requests              2.25.1
requests-oauthlib     1.3.0
requests-toolbelt     0.8.0
requests-unixsocket   0.1.5
```

My python versions are:

```
Python -V -> Python 2.7.17
Python3 -V -> Python 3.6.9
pip -V -> pip 21.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
pip3 -V -> pip 21.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

-PD

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python` <--- is that the python from your virtual environment?

Comment: if you work inside virtual environment, the `requests` package need to be installed after the environment is activated. It looks you installed `requests` for the system interpreter for 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The issues was resolved using installation.

```
 sudo apt-get install python-requests --upgrade
```